# How to switch between different version of gem installed?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber, rack

I have three version of rack installed on local machine (`rack (1.4.1, 1.3.6, 1.3.5)`). For some gem (such as `Cucumber`), it requires a lower version of `rack` to be activated?

I have tried with `bundle` but there is no good.

When executed, `cucumber` will still use the activated rack with version `1.4.1` of the system. `Bundle`specifies **which gem should be installed** but doesn't ensure **which gem will be activated**.

How could I activate certain version of `rack`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can specify a version in gemfile of your project

```
gem "rack",  "1.3.5"
```

**Pointed by `matt`:**

To use gem specified in Gemfile:

```
bundle exec cucumber
```

Comment: However, when executed, `cucumber` will still use the activated rack with version `1.4.1` of the system. `Bundle`specifies **which gem should be installed** but doesn't ensure **which gem will be activated**.

Comment: @steven.yang You can use [`bundle exec`](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-exec.1.html) to execute a command using the gem versions specified in your `Gemfile`. E.g. `bundle exec cucumber`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) it will manage it for you.