# Trouble "activating" gem version

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm taking a coursera intro class on rails and having some trouble with the gems.

When I run rspec on a new rails project I get this error:

```
/Users/mme/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in `block in setup': 
You have already activated poltergeist 1.9.0, but your Gemfile requires poltergeist 1.6.0. 
Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
```

According to [How to switch between different version of gem installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703286/how-to-switch-between-different-version-of-gem-installed), I should be able to use `bundle exec [gem]`

```
$ bundle exec poltergeist
bundler: command not found: poltergeist
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

That doesn't make sense - I've used poltergeist previously:

```
$ bundle install | grep poltergeist
Using poltergeist 1.6.0
```

Does anyone have some advice on how to reconcile this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
bundle exec rspec
```

the error suggests "Prepending `bundle exec` to your command" - which literally means adding `bundle exec` before the `rspec` command.